# MS Access chart time values

Tags: vba, datetime, ms-access, charts

I have chart and I supply it with values like this:

```
TASK Time
19  2:55:12
20  3:00:00
21  3:00:00
22  5:00:00
23  7:33:00
24  7:45:00
25  9:49:48
26  51:02:42
27  72:16:12
28  208:57:00
```

but for some reason my chart looks like this:

[image]

I want it to show values like 24:00:00, 48:00:00..., but it gives me 00:00:00 every 24 hours. To get these data I am using this function:

```
Public Function FormatHourMinuteSecond( _
  ByVal datTime As Date, _
  Optional ByVal strSeparator As String = ":") _
  As String

' Returns count of days, hours, minutes, and seconds of datTime
' converted to hours, minutes, and seconds as a formatted string
' with an optional choice of time separator.
'
' Example:
'   datTime: #10:03:55# + #20:01:24#
'   returns: 30:05:19
'
' 2014-06-17. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

  Dim strHour       As String
  Dim strMinuteSec  As String
  Dim strHours      As String
    Debug.Print Fix(datTime) * 24
    Debug.Print Hour(datTime)
  strHour = CStr(Fix(datTime) * 24 + Hour(datTime))
  ' Add leading zero to minute and second count when needed.
  strMinuteSec = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(datTime)), 2) & strSeparator & Right("0" & CStr(Second(datTime)), 2)
  strHours = strHour & strSeparator & strMinuteSec

  FormatHourMinuteSecond = strHours

End Function
```

Comment: Hi.  Why is datTime a Date type versus a String? Also you can try Format() to pad zeros (e.g. - `Format("2:55:12", "hh:nn:ss")` returns "02:55:12").

Comment: Also, is the input a sum of two time values, or what does that Example mean?

Comment: this function is intended for numbers like 3 if you make Format("3", "hh:nn:ss") then the result would be 00:00:00 and not 72:00:00 which is what i want.  That's why I have this function.

Comment: Someone more clever than me stated: _I don’t think you can do it with the modern charts, but I could be wrong. With the classic charts, use double-precision for the data and then you can format as date and or time on the axis format._

Answer (score 0):

A formatted time becomes text, thus 2, 20, and 200 will be sorted together.

Try as suggested by Mark to add leading zeroes by modifying this line:

```
strHour = Right("00" & CStr(Fix(datTime) * 24 + Hour(datTime)), 3)
```

Comment: It will only add two zeros before hours so the output is like this: `0012:12:01`. What I need is to let the chart show only the string on the Y axis. But it seems confused thinking it is and actual date not only a string thus it shows me for every 24 hours `00:00:00`

Comment: No. It will output `012:12:01` - leading zero(es) up to 99. But without your application, I don't know what is going on.

Comment: I have a chart with this rowsource: `SELECT TaskReport.TASK, FormatHourMinuteSecond(TaskReport.Duration/24) AS [Duration Hours] FROM TaskReport ORDER BY [TaskReport]![Duration] ASC;`

The query returns values like this: Task 1 Duration 0.12; Task 2 Duration 0.99, Task 3 Duration 1.442 and so on.

There is nothing but chart in the form now. I just need it to show values like 24:00:00, 48:00:00, ... on the Y axis. But it shows me for every 24 hours 00:00:00

Comment: the values are correct from the function it will show for example Task 1 duration 24:00:00, Task 2 Duration 48:00:00. Only problem is with the chart which for some reason shows me for every 24 hours values 00:00:00

Comment: These videos by one of our experts may help you: [How To Make a Graph with Microsoft Access](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhgNX6BWWmk) and [Tool and Code: Manipulate Graphs in Microsoft Access using VBA](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zc5WAPderyQ).